# Newbie to HQL - Date conversions in Hive - extract Year from free flow text varchar100

Tags: date, hive, hue

I have a simple HQL statement which works.  I want to be able to count the occurrence's by Year or by Month.  The data Quality is not good,and the `incorporationdate` column is held as a `varchar100` and contains free flowing text and nulls

So I cannot use Substring or YEAR as I need to only perform a extract on the format mm/dd/yyyy to pull out the Year or month. Ideally I would like to create a `View` and create 2 new Columns , one to show the year and one to show the month this would be the perfect scenario.

```
select 
incorporationdate, count(incorporationdate) from default.chjp2
group by companynumber,incorporationdate
```

===================================================

Regards
JP

Comment: HQL supports the `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ...` syntax in expressions [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) so it should be possible to default records with a malformed date value in a first step

Answer (score 0):

you could use `if` and test any condition you want before using `substring`:

`select if(date is not null and date rlike '^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$', substr(7),null)`